# Swift library to parse Music XML

Tags: ios, music, game, xml, swift

I make a piano game with falling plates(tiles). I have xml files (music xml) that I want to use in the game. Is there a Swift library for simple Parsing music xml files?

After that I need to convert data (notes, tempo) into falling plates.

I have tried several frameworks and libraries, but they are suitable for displaying sheet and I could not change the code inside them for my purposes

UPDATE:
I think the solution is .midi file format!

[image]

Comment: I removed the second question because it was off-topic here, thanks for your understanding! :-)